# APFS File Clone doesn't work as expected with Sparse Files

Tags: apfs, virtualization

I have a Virtual Machine disk image in the RAW format (`.img` extension) that was created sparse with `dd if=/dev/zero of=disk.img bs=1m count=0 seek=10240`. As expected, it starts off using 0 bytes and increases when the VM writes data. However, if I then do a `cp` with the `-c` flag, it seems to do a full copy (based on the time taken). At least it is still kept as a sparse file.

To summarise:

1. `cp disk.img disk-copy.img` doesn't preserve sparseness and destination file is the full 10G.
2. `cp -c disk.img disk-copy.img` keeps the sparseness but does a full copy of non sparse parts
3. `cp`-ing a non sparse file works as expected and finishes almost immediately

Is there a way (either with `cp` or with C APIs`) to clone a sparse file?

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing. You write that "cp -c disk.img disk-copy.img keeps the sparseness but does a full copy of non sparse parts" - isn't this what you want with a clone? - How is what you want different from that?

Comment: @jksoegaard see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_File_System#Clones). APFS clones are supposed to not take extra space until you modify them.

Comment: I know. I think you should read the part of your question that I quoted again. You seem to state that it works like it should (I.e. does not take extra space) - so what exactly is your problem? That it takes too long?

Comment: @jksoegaard When you clone a non sparse file, it shares the same blocks on disk instead of copying the blocks. But it seems that cloning a sparse file doesn't share the blocks. (my only evidence of that it the fact that it takes a long time since it's hard to tell if APFS really did clone)

Comment: Ah okay - so the problem is really that you want to know how to determine if the cloned file is really a clone (i.e. takes up no extra space for the data blocks on disk, only takes up space for the metadata)? I.e. you’re worried that because the process wasn’t “instant” that the system copied your data instead of enabling CoW for the clone? Did you check the available space count on the drive before and after making the clone? Which macOS version are you on?

Comment: @jksoegaard I'm on Big Sur 11.6. The available space does go down by a large amount after the cloning the sparse file. I'm fairly certain that `cp -c` works properly for non sparse files but it doesn't seem to work for sparse files.

Comment: Most probably a bug then - I can check the source code later to see if we can confirm that. “cp -c” just uses clonefile() internally.

Comment: @jksoegaard where's the source code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't seem to be happening anymore (I even checked with [apfs-clone-checker](https://github.com/dyorgio/apfs-clone-checker), also, the copy now happens instantly). I'm not sure if this is because of a fix in Monterey, but since I can't get back to Big Sur I'll have to chalk it up as either a bug or an error in my testing method previously.

Comment: Good to know - it was a bug then :-)